# Can hive single orcfile'stripe be splited to smaller size?

Tags: hive, mapper, orc

Example, an orcfile's block and stripesize are same, are 256M, but the split size is 100M. How does the orcfile be splitted?

Answer (score 0):

ORC is splitted on stripe level, in your case 256M, smaller split is not possible.

Stripe size is configurable in `TBLPROPERTIES("orc.stripe.size"="268435456")`, split size is configurable in these settings (example for Tez):

```
set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;
set tez.grouping.max-size=104857600; 
set tez.grouping.min-size=32000; --smaller files will be possibly be combined
```

In this case each mapper will receive whole stripes (256M) or less if there are smaller stripes, stripes will not be splitted on smaller chunks.

Comment: But, when i set the max_split.size is 256M the map num is 13; set 128M map num is 13; set 100M the map num is 26;  set 50M the map num is 52.I don't know why if the stripe can't be split?